# Where to start with sequencer

Tags: objective-c, core-audio, sequence, audiounit

I am looking to create a 16th note sequencer that triggers an AU to play when the note is selected in the interface, I've worked out the length of the 16th note in seconds 15/tempo. How would i go about doing this.

Answer (score 1):

The [MusicPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/MusicPlayerServices_Reference/Reference/reference.html) might be a start.